# font problem in photoshop used via playonlinux

Tags: wine, fonts, playonlinux, photoshop

I had installed Photoshop under Playonlinux , but i got a problem with fonts in the dialog; for example when i want to create a new PSD document as shown:

[image]

I had searched in google for a solution , and i had seen many people said that they resolved the problem by installing Microsoft fonts but i din't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this open Terminal using (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type the below:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

Reopen Photoshop and it should work. This basically installs the Standard Microsoft Fonts onto your computer and configures them in wine.